# how to solve this matrix equation? eigen vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have the following equation.

How can I solve it?

AW = BW

Where A,B,W are MATRICES. B is invertible.

Any hint to solve it in Matlab?

Comment: AW=BW suggests that A=B. This is true for any W that can be multiplied by A. What do you mean by "solve" in this case?

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve AW = WB?  If so, this is the general eigenvalue problem and Matlab has libraries for that.